Get product listing by categoryId
How to get product listing by categoryId using Shopware\Core\Framework\Context??
For information I should use this function in scheduled tasks, that's why I cannot use SalesChannelContext.

This question is similar to: Check products by categoryId using scheduled task. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
